# How to delete a folder named "help..file.." in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows

Recently I found a weird folder named "help..file.." showing up in my laptop. It's located in C:\Users\My_User_Name\

I've tried deleting it by pressing Delete button on my keyboard, and I've also tried using

```
del help..file..
```

command and

```
del help..file..
```

command to delete it, but the above methods all failed.

I think maybe this folder is created by some mischievous malware hidden in my laptop. How can I remove this folder? What else can I do with my laptop?

Comment: Not sure this is the right place for this question, probably http://superuser.com/ is more apt.

Comment: Nevertheless... I can delete it fine in Win 7 with a plain old `del help..file..`. However, if you can't, try `del "help..file.."`. If still no luck, do you have permissions on that file, is it locked? Perhaps show the actual console output in your question when you try and delete it. Also, see [microsoft help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/cant-delete-file-folder#1TC=windows-7). More importantly though, you'll get mor help on superuser.com.

Comment: I can open the folder and view what's inside(which is empty).

Comment: del "help..file.." returns an error message saying "can't find C:\Users\My_User_Name\help..file.."

Comment: Can you do a `dir` and copy the result into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally use

```
rd help..file..\
```

to remove this weird folder.